# All digits with one operation

Tags: formation-of-numbers

I can't find this very easy, simple puzzle here, so here goes:

Using all ten digits from 0 to 9 exactly one time, find an equation (using =, not !=, don't be silly) that uses only one of the operators [+, -, /, *].

To be clear, I'm looking for answers of the form

abcd + efg = hij

ab * cd = efghij

etc.

I found an answer for addition/substraction years ago as an elementary school homework problem. But I'm curious if there's one for multiplication/division.

Comment: For just abc + def = ghij you can go up to 96 examples.

Comment: To use only one of the operators mean one instance of the operator or one type of operators (i.e. a+b+c=d uses only the '+')?

Comment: Only one instance, as per the answers below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of examples for addition:

> There are 84 examples if we agree that a+b=c is no different than b+a=c. All of them are in form of "*abc + def = ghij*" and "*ab + cdef = ghij*".
>  i.e. 246 + 789 = 1035

The same lots of substraction examples (switch the numbers from addition):

> i.e. 1035 - 789 = 246

Many multiplication examples:

> There are 22 examples of multiplication. They appear in the forms of "*a x bcde = fghij*" and "*ab x cde = fghij*"
>  i.e. 27 * 594 = 16038

The same many division examples (switch the numbers from multiplication):

> i.e. 16038 / 594 = 27

Some things to take into consideration when finding such examples:

> 1. "1" is usually in front of the largest number you create (statistics).
> 2. You have to decide how many digits to "use up" for each number you create.
> 3. The last digit is the easiest to find because it is not dependent on any other digit.
> The rest just lines up after you do this.

Comment: This is the most complete answer. As a comment, I don't think there are "lots", maybe a dozen or so.

Comment: I would only count 48 examples of addition/substraction ( a+b = b +a). There's only 9 different examples of multiplication/substraction!

Comment: In fact, there's only 9 combinations for multiplication/division, apart from the 48 for addition/substraction

Comment: @rarpm A little more than that :)

Comment: Oh yeah! I didn't check for the single-digit solutions :P

Comment: there are actually 84 (x+y/y+x collapsed) unique solutions for addition and subtraction - the 48 abc+def patterns, plus 36 others that are ab+cdef.   the multiplication and division counts (22) are correct.

Comment: That right. I forgot about them.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple solutions:
Here are two I quickly found:

> ```
>   742
>  +356
>  ----
>  1098
> ```

.

> ```
>   724
>  +365
>  ----
>  1089
> ```

Reasoning:

> $7+3 = 10$, $4 + 5 = 9$, $2+6 = 8$.
>  You can arrange them in every combination so that 7 and 3 go on the hundreds places, and the 2 other combinations can be on the tenths and units places because there is no carriage from their sum.  You can re-arrange them to get 8 combinations I think.

Working on the multiplication.

Comment: Yes, these are I found as well! And you can of course invert the digits, too.

Answer (score 2):

Many examples can be built for additions and subtractions.

Here is my multiplication example -

> $5694 * 3 = 17082$ which can also be presented as $17082 / 3 = 5694$

Comment: Nice! May I ask how you found it?

Comment: Microsoft Excel! :)

Answer (score 1):

I brute-forced a list of [2548 equations](http://pastebin.com/cAYwdfUa) meeting these criteria. There are in total 5096 equations with the operator on either side of the equal sign.